# Unable to cancel wix installation custom action which has async await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, wix, wix3

I have a custom action which downloads a large file (~800MB); so as to show progress of download, I've made this action as async-await.

But on hitting 'Cancel' from Wix UI, only after complete file is downloaded, the installation is cancelled.

Is there a way to cancel it right after user cancels the installation?

CustomAction.cs

```
public class CustomActions
{
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult DownloadImage(Session session)
        {
            InstallerLog.Log(session, "DownloadImage", "Entry Point :", InstallerLog.LoggerLevel.Info);
            string url = session["DOWNLOAD_URL"];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(new UriBuilder(url).Path);
            string downloadPath = "SomePath";
            string downloadFile = Path.Combine(downloadPath, fileName);

            try
            {
                DownloadImageFile DIF = new DownloadImageFile(session);
                DIF.DownloadFile(url, downloadFile);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                InstallerLog.Log(session, "DownloadImage", "Error: " + exc.Message, InstallerLog.LoggerLevel.Error);
                session.Message(InstallMessage.Error, new Record { FormatString = exc.Message });
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }
            return ActionResult.Success;
}

class DownloadImageFile
    {
        private volatile bool _completed;
        private Session session;

        public DownloadImageFile(Session sess)
        {
            session = sess;
        }

        public void DownloadFile(string address, string location)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Uri Uri = new Uri(address);
            _completed = false;
            InstallerLog.Log(session, "DownloadFile", "Starting file download");

            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);

            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgress);
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)");
            client.DownloadFileAsync(Uri, location);

            while (client.IsBusy) { } // THIS BLOCKS MY THREAD
        }

        public bool DownloadCompleted { get { return _completed; } }

        public static double previousBytes = 0;
        private void DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((double)e.BytesReceived - previousBytes) / e.TotalBytesToReceive * 100 > 0.5)
            {
                previousBytes = e.BytesReceived;
                InstallerLog.Log(session, "DownloadFile", "File downloaded: " + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
            }
        }

        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true) // THIS IS NEVER CALLED
            {
                InstallerLog.Log(session, "DownloadFile", "Download has been canceled");
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                InstallerLog.Log(session, "DownloadFile", "Error encountered while downloading image file:" + e.Error.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                InstallerLog.Log(session, "DownloadFile", "Download completed");
            }

            _completed = true;
        }
    }
```

My Product.wxs has entry for CA as:

```
<CustomAction Id="DownloadImageCA" Impersonate="yes" BinaryKey="PreConBin" DllEntry="DownloadImage" Return="check" Execute="immediate" />
```

Comment: You should not do this in your setup (there are many reasons) - can you do it on application launch instead?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, actually I have no idea how that is done. If you can please point me to any document, it will be great. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with WiX Burn bundles? `Setup.exe` builder which allows you to download installers from the Internet as part of its operation to run setups in sequence for you (chained installers): https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/ - it looks like you are making an MSI and not a setup.exe?

Comment: Yes I am creating a msi. Workflow: I am trying to set up a HyperV machine. The msi does some machine validation checks, then downloads the vhdx image as mentioned above, and then creates the VM